# Selectize.js match incorrect word

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a large amount of selectize elements, one of which is "gender". Gender can, as one would expect, be `male` and `female`. If you search for any substring which match male, so `m, ma, mal, male` it will still highlight `female` and upon tab select that one.

Is there any way I can override this behaviour? I don't know if it's a bug in sifter, but I suspect what happens is that "empty" is after "fe", so `ØØmale` is lower ranked lexicographically than `female`. Which makes no sense though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is just that Selectize matches in the whole string, not only at start.
I give a solution in the [Filter by only first letter · Issue #795](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/795).

To repeat it here: Add this to your options:

```
  score: function (search)
  {
    return function (option)
    {
//      console.log(JSON.stringify(option));
      if (option.name.indexOf(search) === 0) // Here, 'name' is the property identified by labelField
      {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```